# How can I saved my outputs in specific folder in cplex?

Tags: output, cplex, opl

I have an OPL project in Cplex, and I get all my outputs as csv files. All of them are saved in a folder of my project; however, I want to know how can I give it a specific path? I want to save them where I get all my inputs. Is there any way that I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
tuple t
{
string firstname;
int number;
}

{t} s={<"Nicolas",2>,<"Alexander",3>};

execute
{
var f=new IloOplOutputFile("c:\\temp\\export.csv");
for(var i in s)
{
f.writeln(i.firstname,";",i.number,";");
}
f.close();
}
```

writes the result in the folder "c:/temp".

I changed a bit https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3fd44d41-210b-4b81-a005-819530d6377b&ps=25

Comment: Hi Alex. I wonder if I could ask you to take a bit more care over your posts? I sometimes find the code formatting is broken, there are case errors, punctuation is largely absent, and chatty items are added despite being discouraged here. I appreciate it is tempting to dash off any old thing in order to acquire reputation points, but the core community is keen to amass a Q&A resource of high quality here, as much as possible. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I do not intend to pretend I provided anything new when it s not. Would you prefer I simply provided the answer without mentioning where it came from ?

Comment: Err, no. I would like you to make the changes I mentioned in my comment above, and I am now struggling to understand how my request wasn't clear. If you are copy+pasting from another forum then I expect adding a link is better than not adding one, but here the code formatting was broken, and punctuation was missing, and chatty material was included in the paste. All of those things might be OK on a discussion forum, but we try to discourage it here - Stack Overflow is not a forum.

Answer (score 0):

I supposed you use an `IloOplOutputFile` to create the output? In that case note that you can specify an arbitrary path as a constructor argument (see for example Alex's answer). Moreover, notice that the IloOplModel class has a function [resolvePath](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.9.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/IloOplModel.html#resolvePath) that resolves the path of a resource. So you can do something like

```
var path = thisOplModel.resolvePath("inputfile");
```

to get the path to one of your input files. From that you can construct a path for your output files.